# Audio Bytes mixing

Tags: delphi, wave

Just can't obtain a correct sound when I try to mix wave bytes with others...

Depending on a _style (sOverlay or sOverwrite), I loop for samples and call OverByte with a pointer to a previous SmallInt and a new byte value...

```
procedure OverByte(var _pbyte : ^TByte; const _byte : TByte);
begin
     case _style of
          sOverlay   : _pbyte^ := Math.Min(0, Math.Max(255, (_pbyte^ + _byte) div 2));
          sOverwrite : _pbyte^ := _byte;
     end;
end;
```

When I fill my buffer with sOverWrite, I have a correct sound...
When I fill my buffer with sOverlay I do not have the correct sound...

How I know is simple :

I fill 2000 ms at 2400hz on Left and Right Channels : Correct Sound
I fill the same buffer for 1000ms at 4800 on only Left Channel : Sound is the same...so incorrect...

Is the formula for 2 audiobytes RESTRICT(0..255, (A + B) / 2) correct ? or what ?

Comment: Yes of course... Inverted Min Max... I test it and come back to you

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to tell us what a `TByte` is, but I'll assume it is a `Byte`.

Your formula is essentially

```
Min(0, Max(255, (A + B) div 2));
```

Suppose that A = 70 and B = 150.

Then AVG = (A + B) div 2 = 110.

Then Max(255, AVG) = Max(255, 110) = 255, since 255 is greater than 110.

Finally, Min(0, 255) = 0, since 0 is less than 255.

Do you see the problem?

You clearly want

```
Max(0, Min(255, (A + B) div 2));
```

which can be written

```
EnsureRange((A + B) div 2, 0, 255).
```

However, since A and B are bytes, A >= 0 and B >= 0 so that A + B >= 0 and thus (A + B) div 2 >= 0.

For the same reason, A <= 255 and B <= 255 so that A + B <= 510 and thus (A + B) div 2 <= 255.

Therefore,

```
EnsureRange((A + B) div 2, 0, 255) = (A + B) div 2.
```

So you are making things complicated for no good reason!

Comment: TByte is a SmallInt....

Comment: @blueperfect: Yes. But `EnsureRange((A + B) div 2, 0, 255)` is better because it is easier to read. Now you may object, "But the original `Min`/`Max` solution is already very easy to read, and no one would misread or misinterpret it!" But then I'd reply, "But you just did!". Also, since you know that `(A + B) div 2` ALWAYS will be a number between 0 and 255, you should just write it like that. (Unless you need the extra CPU work to heat your apartment.)

Comment: Wait... `TByte` is a `SmallInt`? That's almost as bad as defining a boolean variable named `False` with the value of `True`!

Comment: SmallInt is used to store the calcultation of the sine (so I have minus and plus), but on range of -128 to +128...) That is a excalty 8 bits = 1 byte... So for convenience, I will have a TMemoryStream of TByte, and treat them as SmallInt when calculating... What is so horrible ? The real error I encounter was a misplaced Min/Max logic, where the case just could not be...due to Delphi way to cast from a SmallInt to an Integer !

Comment: The formula (A+ B) div 2 remains the right one...

Comment: `SmallInt` is a signed 16-bit integer (two bytes wide). If I read source code and come across `TByte`, I'd automatically expect it to be a `Byte`. So if it in fact isn't, that will confuse me.

Comment: You are right... I didnt tell you the first code was a c++ code and SmallInt (16 bits) was used to replace short (8 bits).. For calculations that has no impacts...

Comment: TByte is TYPEd as SmallInt, but expects only -127..127

Comment: @blueperfect, any reason why you're using integers, rather than floating point values? The sine calculations will result in floating point values and casting them to integer will introduce rounding errors. In addition to that, the wave 8-bit PCM format is using unsigned bytes (range 0-255) so what you're doing here isn't standard especially if you want to save the resulting mix to a wave file.

Comment: Bad to you dsp_user as the computed byte is obtain by a sine over herz and then factorized by a precalculated factor from samples...to obtain a byte scoped value...I am sure that the two bytes to be combined are in scope of 0..255 even if the variable have a size of 1 .. 2 ... or more...

Comment: When I say 0..255 that includes -127 to 127...

Comment: The reason why using integer should be obvious as it then can be aligned easily for processing large amount of datas...often found for decibels and pixels...

Comment: For your information I develop under c++builder 5.0 that includes Pascal Object's compiler... So when I use the Pascal types I quickly get lost with sizes...

Answer (score 0):

After testing, adding two SmallInt could overflow, so Min should be used as first restriction for obtaining an Integer under 256...

and then Max to obtain a Positive Value...

Then the cast to a simple SmallInt could be performed correctly...

But you pointed me to the fact that two bytes added and divided by 2 cannot be over 255 or under 0 !!!

I now have the right sound on both channels...

Thanks...